# Get records that have 2 or more entries in a joining table matching a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

### customers

`id` INT PK
`name` VARCHAR

### details

`id` INT PK
`detail_name` VARCHAR

### customers_details

`customer_id` INT FK
`detail_id` INT FK
`value` INT

---

For each `customer` I have a set of `details`.
The following query will get all users that have the detail #2 equals to 10:

```
SELECT c.* FROM customers c
INNER JOIN customers_details cd ON cd.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE cd.detail_id = 2 AND cd.value = 10
```

My problem is that I need to get all `customers` that have 2 or more specific `details`. For example: I want to get all `customers` that have detail #2 = 10 **AND** detail #3 = 20.

Is there a simple way to do that using SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that:

```
select c.*
from customers_details cd
inner join customers c
    on c.id = cd.customer_id
where cd.detail_id in (2,10)
group by cd.customer_id
having     
    sum(cd.detail_id = 2 and cd.value = 1) = 1
    and sum(cd.detail_id = 10) = 1
```

What I do here is:

- Grouping details by customer
- Sum 1 if the condition is satisfied. If there is a detail = 2
- Having filters only customers which has the both conditions
- I use the WHERE clause in order to filter less results for HAVING filters again trying to avoid a full-scan.

Regards,

Comment: Definetely the best answer, without using any subselects. Worked as a charm. Thank you very much!

Comment: it's misguided to believe that subselects are bad. In fact an exists query is often better because it can sort of short-circuit the full join.

Comment: And that summing notation is entirely non-standard. In a case like this there's absolutely no reason at all to use it. And the way your question was written it appeared that the value was significant to you. This query doesn't even use it nor does it require pairing up detail_id and value within the same row. Whatever works for you though.

Comment: Oops, I really forgot the value. But you're totally able to add another condition inside the sum. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by and having

```
SELECT c.customer_id
, min(c.name) customer_name
, count(cd.customer_id) detailcount
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN customers_details cd ON cd.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE cd.Value is not null
group by c.customer_id
having COUNT(cd.customer_id)>=2
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I need. Check my comments on Phoenix's answer.

Comment: Add a check to ensure that customer_details. value is not null. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You're just looking for customers that have more than one detail ID, where one equals 2 and one equals 20?

```
SELECT c.customer_id, count (*) FROM customers c
INNER JOIN customers_details cd ON cd.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE cd.detail_id IN (2, 20) 
GROUP BY c.customer_id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

This should give you every customer_id that has a detail_id of 2 *and* a detail_id of 20

Comment: No, that's not it. I'm searching for all customers that have two details (ids 2 and 3 for example) and each detail should have one value (10 and 20 for example). Each record on customers_details has a value associated.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from customers as c
where exists (
    select 1
    from customer_details as cd
    where
        cd.customer_id = c.customer_id and
        (detail_id = 2 and value = 10 or detail_id = 3 and value = 20)
    having count(*) = 2
)
```

Be careful with parens. Not sure if some platforms might require a grouping on the subquery with a `having` clause. You can add a dummy group by like `group by cd.customer_id` if it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count (distinct detail_id) = 2` to select all customers that have both detail ids

```
select c.* from customers_details cd
join customers c on c.id = cd.customer_id
where (detail_id = 2 and value = 10)
or (detail_id = 3 and value = 20)
group by customer_id
having count (distinct detail_id) = 2
```

Comment: Unfortunately after grouping you can no longer refer to all the columns of c. I know some platforms let you do that, but it's really a bad idea. And that's why a subquery works better.

Comment: mysql allows it, and this is exactly when it's appropriate to use this feature: when all values you're selecting in the group are the same. Since we're grouping by customer_id, all values c.* will be the same for each group. see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: It has to be a primary key. In this case it is but it's not always clear that that's true even with a naming convention that uses `_id` suffixes. It's a bad habit in general and definitely not portable.